# How can I prevent a nested Bootstrap collapse element from firing .show() on the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

Here is a jsfiddle of my setup;

http://jsfiddle.net/7LBr5/1/

You'll notice I have indicator arrows on the parent accordion and a function that toggles them when the accordion shows and hides. The problem is that the inner collapse areas (used to hide product details) trigger the function that toggles the arrows on the parent. It seems that the .show() event must be firing on the parent collapse element when the child is actually the one collapsing.

How can I fix this so that the child collapse doesn't toggle the arrows on the parent?

Here is the code for my function;

```
$('.collapse').on('show', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".icon-chevron-right").removeClass("icon-chevron-right").addClass("icon-chevron-down");}).on('hide', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".icon-chevron-down").removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-right");});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just stop the event from propagating to the parent on the button click using `event.stopPropagation`, so that it doesn't trigger the click event on the accordion after executing the click event on the button.

```
$thisButton.click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
//.. Code follows
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2Dr3/)**

Also by the way you don't need to perform an each on the selector to bind the click event, instead just specify the selector for click event itself

```
$(".btn-switch").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $thisButton = $(this);
    $thisButton.toggleClass("btn-primary btn-danger");
    if ($(this).hasClass('btn-danger')) {
        $thisButton.html('<i class="icon-remove-circle icon-white"></i> Remove');
        $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('.rental-count').val('1');
        $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('input').change();
    } else {
        $thisButton.html('<i class="icon-ok-circle icon-white"></i> Add to Quote');
        $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('input').val('');
        $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('input').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).parents('.thumbnail').find('input').change();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is an obvious solution. When I tried it before I must have had a syntax error. :-/

Comment: @JosiahSprague probably you tried on the each callback before? Is this working?

Comment: I tried function() { event.stopPropagation() } before. You can tell I don't spend much time with JavaScript. It's working now with your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to use

```
$(".btn-switch").click(function (e) {

//you code 
return false;

});
```